# How do I plot contours on top of a hexbin plot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have two arrays, `x` and `y`, both with values within a well defined range. I am able to create a hexbin plot ([see image](http://goo.gl/NBUQA)), however, I would now like to normalize these distributions and draw contour plots around them. I am not so interested in the counts within each hexbin. Instead I am interested in showing the contours corresponding to 1, 2 and 3 standard deviations (σ). I hope to have an output showing the contours similar to [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/tricontour_vs_griddata.html) example. The distribution is Gaussian. I would greatly appreciate any input on this.

Comment: Can you please clarify in your question whether you are using numpy or matplotlib?

Comment: Sorry about that. I am using matplotlib.

Comment: Link dead. This is why it's a bad idea to ask people to go off site to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the hexbin documentation https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html you should be able to access the (x,y) locations of the bins and the values from the returned variable. For example:

```
h = hexbin(...)
xy = h.get_offsets()
v = h.get_array()
```

You can use these to draw your contour.

Note that the documentation is incorrect and says `get_offset()` should be called, but that function does not exist, it is `get_offsets()`.

In addition, when `hexbin` is called with `xscale='log'` and `yscale='log'`, then `get_offsets()` only returns `array([[0., 0.]])`.

Comment: See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18045 for bug report